# HTML: Add background style with a data attribute

Tags: html, angular

I want to pass the color passed inside my object to the icon tag's style like this :

```
  <div class="icon-box" style="background: ${data.color}">
    <i class="material-icons">{{ data.icon }}</i>
  </div>
```

The object i have is like this :

```
  {
    icon: 'add_alert',
    color: '#ffaa00',
  }
```

Is there a way for it to work please?

Comment: you want to change the icon background color>

Comment: I pass to my service an object containing data and one of them is a color so i want to consume it inside a div tag like this data.color... is it possible?

Comment: sure we can. can you show me the object which has color property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [style binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#style-binding) syntax:

```
[style.background-color]="data.color"
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k4s1x7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for a demo.

Answer (score 1):

you can do using `ngStyle`

```
 <div class="icon-box" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': data?.color}">
        <i class="material-icons">{{ data.icon }}</i>
  </div>
```

[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1smeag)